# Angular Translate with JSON file not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGLjh/11/)
Fiddle is attached to see if i have included all the files in my htmlfile.No error coming while running but in h2 tag i am seeing HEADLINE only instead of its value. my JSON file name is locale-en_US.json

Html Code

```
<div ng-app="app">
<h2 translate='HEADLINE'></h2>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', [
     'pascalprecht.translate'
]);

myApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
            .useStaticFilesLoader({
                prefix: 'locale-',
                suffix: '.json'
            })
            .preferredLanguage('en')
            .fallbackLanguage(['da', 'fr']).useLocalStorage();
});
})();
```

json file

```
{

"HEADLINE":"hI ITS RUNNING FROM JSON"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose it's the main problem on your project but there's no way any json can be loaded by the fiddle you created since you haven't attached one there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there.
I only see you defined **app** as a variable,
where does the **myApp** come from?